# Android (NDK) openSoftInput in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, keyboard

I'm currently porting a framework to Android NDK. And I have to use the on screen keyboard once in a while. Opening and closing the keyboard works so far..

But I have a problem with the focus of the keyboard in landscape mode (portrait mode works fine) - the part of the screen that I colored red is still reacting on touch input as if there was no keyboard over it, then the one uncolored row of the keyboard works as expected and the greenish part over the keyboard does not receive touch input.

[image: Keyboard Focus demonstration]

I have tested this with a usual Android App as well. Same result (code for this see at the end of the question).

I'm opening the keyboard when klicking on the "Press me!" button and close it with the back softkey. This is the code that is called to open/close:

```
//adapted from https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/Tk3g00wLKhk/TJQucoaE_asJ
void AndroidCore::openOnScreenKeyboard(bool open){
    // Attaches the current thread to the JVM. 
    jint lResult; 
    jint lFlags = 0; 

    JavaVM* javaVM = view->native_activity->vm;
    JNIEnv* jniEnv;
    bool attached = false;

    if(javaVM->GetEnv((void**)&jniEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6) ==JNI_EDETACHED){
        JavaVMAttachArgs attachArgs;
        attachArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
        attachArgs.name = "NativeThread";
        attachArgs.group = NULL;

        jint result = javaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&jniEnv, &attachArgs);
        if(result == JNI_ERR){
            return;
        }
        attached = true;
    } 

    // Retrieves Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE. 
    jclass ClassContext = jniEnv->FindClass("android/content/Context"); 
    jfieldID FieldINPUT_METHOD_SERVICE = jniEnv->GetStaticFieldID(ClassContext, "INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE", "Ljava/lang/String;"); 
    jobject INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE = jniEnv->GetStaticObjectField(ClassContext, FieldINPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

    jclass ClassNativeActivity = jniEnv->FindClass("android/app/NativeActivity");
    jobject lNativeActivity = view->native_activity->clazz;

    // Runs getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE). 
    jclass ClassInputMethodManager = jniEnv->FindClass("android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager");
    jmethodID MethodGetSystemService = jniEnv->GetMethodID(ClassNativeActivity, "getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;"); 
    jobject lInputMethodManager = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(lNativeActivity, MethodGetSystemService, INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

    // Runs getWindow().getDecorView().
    jmethodID MethodGetWindow = jniEnv->GetMethodID(ClassNativeActivity, "getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;"); 
    jobject lWindow = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(lNativeActivity, MethodGetWindow); 
    jclass ClassWindow = jniEnv->FindClass("android/view/Window");
    jmethodID MethodGetDecorView = jniEnv->GetMethodID(ClassWindow, "getDecorView", "()Landroid/view/View;");
    jobject lDecorView = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(lWindow, MethodGetDecorView);

        // Runs lWindow.getViewToken() 
    jclass ClassView = jniEnv->FindClass("android/view/View"); 
    jmethodID MethodGetWindowToken = jniEnv->GetMethodID(ClassView, "getWindowToken", "()Landroid/os/IBinder;"); 
    jobject lBinder = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(lDecorView, MethodGetWindowToken); 

    if (open) {
        // Runs lInputMethodManager.showSoftInput(...). 
        jmethodID MethodShowSoftInput = jniEnv->GetMethodID(ClassInputMethodManager, "showSoftInput", "(Landroid/view/View;I)Z"); 
        jboolean lResult = jniEnv->CallBooleanMethod(lInputMethodManager, MethodShowSoftInput, lDecorView, lFlags);
    } else { 
        // lInputMethodManager.hideSoftInput(...). 
        jmethodID MethodHideSoftInput = jniEnv->GetMethodID(ClassInputMethodManager, "hideSoftInputFromWindow", "(Landroid/os/IBinder;I)Z"); 
        jboolean lRes = jniEnv->CallBooleanMethod(lInputMethodManager, MethodHideSoftInput, lBinder, lFlags); 
    } 

    // Finished with the JVM. 
    javaVM->DetachCurrentThread(); 
}
```

Java Code with similiar problem:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInput(getWindow().getDecorView(), 0);
                     //same with showSoftInput(button, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

So can anyone imagine, why this focus problem happens? And can someone help me fixing this problem?

Thanks!